# PermissionError [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'After.png'

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I built a Web site using the Django framework, one of which was to process images uploaded by the user and save them in a folder for download, but encountered an error ([Errno 13] Permission denied: After. png'). I use (python3 manage. py runserver) and it works, but it doesn't work when deployed with Apache 2.

I knew it was a problem with the permissions of Ubuntu, but I couldn't fix it after modifying the permissions of the file.
I hope someone can give me some advice. Thank you very much indeed.

My code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

    # use PIL.Image to save picture as 'After.png'
    Image.fromarray(im).save('After.png')

    # for download
    file=open('After.png','rb')  
    response =HttpResponse(file)  
    response['Content-Type']='application/octet-stream'  
    response['Content-Disposition']='attachment;filename="After.png"'  
    return response
```

Error info

```
    PermissionError at /Text_embed/embedding_info/
    [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'After.png'
```

[Error info 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1Wrx.png)

[Permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05vlV.png)

Comment: can you tell what is `im` in your code ?

Comment: Hi @schnee - this is a simple one, your Apache we server doesn’t have sufficient permissions to access files in the way that you have specified. Try building the absolute root to where your image is stored (then try providing read and write access to the directory and files for apache web server).

Comment: @Micheal J Roberts I'm not sure how to do. Can you give me some examples? My absolute root of image is /home/Lenote/After.png. I had try chgrp www-data Lenote/After.png and chmod g+w Lenote/After.png. But it's useless : (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solve this problem, I change the root of image and it work!

Before:

```
        Image.fromarray(im).save('After.png')

        file=open('After.png','rb')
```

After:

```
        Image.fromarray(im).save('/home/Lenote/After.png')

        file=open('/home/Lenote/After.png','rb')
```

Because when I use  `python3 manage.py runserver`  `save('After.png')` will create image as `/home/Lenote/After.png.` But when I use apache2, maybe it will create an image in `/etc/apache2/....` without permission.

Thanks everyone. In especial, thanks Micheal J Roberts : ).